# Relating classes to this program to help better understand how to program with classes

Tags: python, class

I am new to python trying to get a handle on classes and OOP. I just can't seem to think of when I would use a class in a program, so I just decided to try and organize this code with classes before preforming some unit test practice on it. Not sure if adding classes to this would be useful at all but I think it would organize it at the least. Can someone help related Class and objects to this code pls.

```
def Max_Month(max):
    maxind = rainfalllist.index(max)
    maxmonth = months.pop(maxind)
    return maxmonth

def Min_Month(min):
    minind = rainfalllist.index(min)
    minmonth = months.pop(minind)
    return minmonth

def Rain_Fall_Math(rainfalllist):
    ave_rain = sum(rainfalllist) / len(rainfalllist)
    high_rain = max(rainfalllist)
    min_rain = min(rainfalllist)
    print(f"Total Rainfall:{rainfalllist}")
    print(f"The average monthly precipitation:{ave_rain}")
    print(f"The highest monthly precipitation: {high_rain}")
    print(f"The lowest monthly precipitation: {min_rain}")
    print(f"The month(s) with the highest precipitation:",Max_Month(high_rain))
    print(f"The month(s) with the lowest precipitation:",Min_Month(min_rain))

months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
rainfalllist = list()
for month in months:
    _ = float(input(f"What was the precipitation in {month}?"))
    rainfalllist.append(_)
Rain_Fall_Math(rainfalllist)
```

Comment: Which part of OOP confuses you the most? Or generally why would you wanna use OOP instead?

Answer (score 0):

For what your code is trying to do I don't think OOP is the way to go. If you want examples of when to use classes and objects then a good tip is to use them if you want to make your own data structure (similar to struct in c and c++) or abstractify something.
Another thing to keep in mind is that just because you could use OOP doesn't mean its the only way to accomplish something.
You should also look at the 4 pillars of OOP, abstraction, inheritance, polymorphism, and encapsulation.

Say you wanted to represent a lot of people with their own attributes and apply functions to them.

You could do this OOP like this

```py
class Human:
    humans = [] # array of all humans

    def __init__(self, name, age, hairclr, eyeclr, favfood, house, height):
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age
        self.hairclr = hairclr 
        self.eyeclr = eyeclr 
        self.favfood = favfood 
        self.house = house
        self.height = height 

        Human.humans.append(self) 
    
    def growOld(self, years):
        self.age += years 
        self.height += years * .04
    
    def moveHouses(self, newhouse):
        self.house = newhouse 
    
    def foo(self, a,b,c):
        pass

    def interact(self, anotherhuman):
        if self.name == anotherhuman:
            greet()
            talk()
            saygoodbye()
        if self.age < another.human.age:
            stuff()

    def __add__(self, anotherhuman):
        # DUNDER METHODS ARE SUPER COOL LOOK INTO THEM
        #they essentially act as if
        # h1 and h2 were human objects, this method is called if you try to do something like
        # h1 + h2

        self.height += anotherhuman.height
```

I don't think a single example could cover all possibilities of OOP and I think there are better ones where OOP is the way to go, but I think you can see kind of what OOP could be used for.

Another example from one of my projects goes along the lines of this which uses inheritance and polymorphism

```py
from math import sqrt
class UIComponent:
    def __init__(self, x, y, state):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y 
        self.state = state
    
    def getDist(self, x2, y2):
        return sqrt((x2 - self.x)**2 + (y2 - self.y)**2)
    
    def setGlobalCoords(self, c1, c2):
        self.c1 = c1 
        self.c2 = c2 
        update()
    
    def update():
        #stuff
        pass

class TextUiComponent(UIComponent):
    def __init__(self, x,y, state, text):
        super(self, TextUiComponent).__init__(x,y,state)
        self.text = text 
    
    def updateText(self, newtext, newfont):
        self.text = newtext
        self.font = newfont 

        self.update() #from earlier

class ImgUIComponent(UIComponent):
    def __init__(self, x,y, state, img):
        super(self, TextUiComponent).__init__(x,y,state)
        self.img = img 
    
    def transfromImg(self, scale):
        transform(self.img, scale) # or self.img.transfrom(scale) this is all psuedocode
        #other stuff
        setGlobalCoords(scale, 1+scale)
```

If you want to create complex data structures with their own operations or abstract something along with many other cases then consider this paradigm.

There's a lot more to talk about in OOP which I couldn't possibly give a full rundown but this is the gist and I suggest you research more if you're confused, but OOP is a powerful tool.